# All paths of length k from a given vertice

Tags: algorithm, graph

Let's say i have a directed graph G(V,E) with edge cost(real number) ∈ (0,1).For given i,I need to find all the couples of vertices (i,j) starting from i that "match".Two vertices (i,j) match if there is a directed path from i to j with length exactly k(k is a given number that is relatively small and could be considered as constant)with cost >=C(C is a given number).Cost of a path is calculated as the product of it's edges.For example if a path starting from i and ending in j of lenght 2 consists edges e1 and e2 then CostOfpath=cost(e1)*cost(e2).

This has to be done in O(E+V*k).So what i thought is modifying the DFS algorithm updating the distances from given starting vertice i until they reach the length of k.If they don't then we can't have a match.However i am having a hard time finding what exactly i can modify in the DFS.Any ideas?

Comment: Do you imply that edge costs are reals, not integers? Because otherwise the path cost is either 0 either 1.

Comment: @Petr Υes i am sorry,i will correct that!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you need to consider paths with a fixed number of edges in it, dynamic programming often comes to help (while other approaches often fail).

Let's denote `dp[v][j]` the maximal cost of the path from vertex `i` (fixed) to vertex `v` that has exactly `j` edges.

For a starting values, you can set values for `j==1`: `dp[v][1]` is the cost of edge from `i` to `v` (or `0` if no such edge exists). Or if you think on it it will be obvious that you  can set values for `j==0`, not `j==1`: `dp[i][0]` is 1, while `dp[v][0]` can be set to zero for `v!=i`.

Now, if you have values for some `j`, it is easy to calculate values for `j+1`:

```
dp[v][j+1] = max( dp[v'][j] * cost((v', v)) )
```

This is very similar to [Ford-Bellman's algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bellman%E2%80%93Ford_algorithm), only that the latter does not need to track the number of edges and thus can use one-dimensional array.

This gives you the solution in `O((E+V)*k)`. Not exactly what you have requested, but I doubt that there exists solution in `O(E+V*k)`.

(In the solution above, I assume that the constant `C` is positive, and so a zero cost path is equivalent to the path being absolutely absent. If you need, you can specifically account for the `C==0` case.)